# Can I solve the partial derivative (dG/dH)s ? Does it make sense?

Tags: thermodynamics, free-energy

It is possible to express  [image] ,   in terms of Cp, Cv, V, P, kt etc. ?

I know that G and H are both derived from the Legandre transformation of U, so they are the same equivalent representation of internal energy but expressed like G=G(T,P) and H=H(S,P).

So I'm wondering if this partial derivative makes sense...

Comment: Is this a homework problem, or is it just something you dreamed up?

Comment: No, it's not an homework problem. It is something I ask to myself, and I'm quiete curious to know the answer, because I search but didn't find nothing about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$dH=TdS+VdP$$
At constant S, $$dH=VdP$$
$$dG=-SdT+VdP$$
If S is constant, then $$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_PdT+\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial P}\right)_TdP=0$$But,$$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_P=\frac{C_p}{T}$$and$$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial P}\right)_T=-\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P$$So, $$dT=\frac{T}{C_p}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_PdP$$and$$dG=\left[V-S\frac{T}{C_p}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P\right]dP$$Dividing by dH then gives:
$$\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial H}\right)_S=1-\frac{\alpha T}{C_p}S=1+\frac{(G-H)\alpha}{C_p}=1+\frac{\alpha T}{C_p}\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial T}\right)_P$$

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that the $\alpha $ in the last equation is the coefficient of thermal expansion $\alpha  = V^{-1} (\frac{\partial V}{\partial T})_{P} $

Comment: Thanks.  I meant to.  Now that you have done it, there is no need for me to do it.

Comment: I'm generally cautious about subtracting something in the numerator of a fraction. Are you sure that it's G - H in the parentheses on the last line, or is it H - G? Also, isn't the partial of G wrt T at const P equal to -S, not S?

Comment: @timaeus222  Ooops.  Good catch.  Sorry everyone.  I'm going to go back and correct it.  It also looks like I made a sign error in the last term.